# How to count cells based on their font colors on Google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

'I have Found this piece of code below. It does work on cell background color But 
doesn't work on font. Can anyone help?

```
    function sumColoredCells(sumRange,colorRef) {
    var activeRg = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
     var activeSht = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
     var activeformula = activeRg.getFormula();
    var countRangeAddress = activeformula.match(/\((.*)\,/).pop().trim();
   var backGrounds = activeSht.getRange(countRangeAddress).getBackgrounds();
  var sumValues = activeSht.getRange(countRangeAddress).getValues(); 
   var colorRefAddress = activeformula.match(/\,(.*)\)/).pop().trim();
  var BackGround = activeSht.getRange(colorRefAddress).getBackground();
 var totalValue = 0;
 for (var i = 0; i < backGrounds.length; i++)
 for (var k = 0; k < backGrounds[i].length; k++)
 if ( backGrounds[i][k] == BackGround )
    if ((typeof sumValues[i][k]) == 'number')
      totalValue = totalValue + (sumValues[i][k]);
  return totalValue;
 };
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Provide screenshots of what you see and describe what you want to see. Looks like you've just posted a fragment of someone else's code here and asked why it doesn't do what *you* need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this script:

```
/**
* @param {range} countRange Range to be evaluated
* @param {range} colorRef Cell with font color to be searched for in countRange
* @return {number}
* @customfunction
*/
function countFontColoredCells(countFontRange,colorRef) {
  var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var activeSheet = activeRange.getSheet();
  var formula = activeRange.getFormula();

  var rangeA1Notation = formula.match(/\((.*)\,/).pop();
  var range = activeSheet.getRange(rangeA1Notation);
  var bg = range.getFontColors();
  var values = range.getValues();

  var colorCellA1Notation = formula.match(/\,(.*)\)/).pop();
  var colorCell = activeSheet.getRange(colorCellA1Notation);
  var color = colorCell.getFontColor();

  var count = 0;

  for(var i=0;i<bg.length;i++)
    for(var j=0;j<bg[0].length;j++)
      if( bg[i][j] == color )
        count=count+1;
  return count;
};
```

Then you can call this function in your google sheets:

```
=countFontColoredCells(C9:C127,Z20)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function has a lot of problems - in particular, it is taking a range parameter which is never used and instead, the function is operating on the active range in the active sheet. I don't follow what the regular expressions are trying to achieve and it seems an unnecessarily complicated way of iterating through some cells.

This type of operation is problematic if you want to use the function in a spreadsheet cell because if you pass in a range you only have access to the values rather than the actual cells in the range and the formatting information is not available.

You could write a function that takes a range as a string and use that string to get the range from the sheet:

```
   function ColourCounter(rangeString, colourToFind) {

      var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(rangeString);
      var colourMap = {};

      for (var r=1; r<=range.getNumRows(); r++) {
        for (var c=1; c<=range.getNumColumns(); c++) {

          var cell = range.getCell(r, c);

          var colour = cell.getFontColor();

          if (colourMap[colour] == undefined) {
            colourMap[colour] = 1;
          } else {
            colourMap[colour] = colourMap[colour] + 1;
          }
        }
      }
      return colourMap[colourToFind] ? colourMap[colourToFind] : 0;
    }
```

You could then call this from your sheet

```
=ColourCounter("A1:C3", "#ff0000")
```

Be aware however that this function will not be reevaluated if the values or formatting in the range change.

I think you would be much better off using conditional formatting to format the cell based on values in the cells and use the same condition to count the categories.

Comment: @Aidan thanks a tonne for your help, This fella worked properly.

Comment: the function worked fine, but it does count blank cells as well. as cells has a default property of color black the same is being counted by the function even if the cell is blank. Can anything be done in this context?